# GCC, LLVM and MSVC disagree about passing constexpr std::string's content to the runtime world. Who is right?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr, consteval

I tried to create a `std::string` at compile time and pass its contents into the runtime world. Along that I stumbled about this problem:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

template <std::size_t N>
struct ct_to_rt_string {
    consteval ct_to_rt_string(std::string const str) {
        std::copy_n(str.c_str(), N + 1, buffer);
    }

    char buffer[N + 1];
};

constexpr std::string make_ct_std_string() {
    return "compile time text";
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << ct_to_rt_string<make_ct_std_string().size()>(make_ct_std_string()).buffer;
}
```

GCC 12.2 with libstdc++ compiles and gives the expected output:

```
compile time text
```

LLVM 16 with libc++ complains about *not a constant expression* because *not deallocated* memory:

```
<source>:20:34: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    std::cout << ct_to_rt_string<make_ct_std_string().size()>(make_ct_std_string()).buffer;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-16.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:113:38: note: allocation performed here was not deallocated
            return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
                                     ^
1 error generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>:20:34: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
    std::cout << ct_to_rt_string<make_ct_std_string().size()>(make_ct_std_string()).buffer;
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-16.0.0/bin/../include/c++/v1/__memory/allocator.h:113:38: note: allocation performed here was not deallocated
            return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
                                     ^
1 error generated.
```

MSVC 19.35 complains about the constructor not being a *constant expression*:

```
<source>(20): error C7595: 'ct_to_rt_string<17>::ct_to_rt_string': call to immediate function is not a constant expression
```

- [Live Code](https://godbolt.org/z/bdavEGo4x)

Which of the three compilers is right?

Comment: Is gcc doing SSO?  (Short string optimisation)

Comment: @PaulSanders No, it works with very long strings as well.

Comment: Clang's behavior looks very much like a bug to me. The destructor call ought to be part of the evaluation of the template argument. With MSVC I don't know what the issue is, but I don't really understand how `consteval` constructors are supposed to work (see some older questions of mine).

Comment: However, MSVC also complains when a `consteval` function to produce the object is used instead and that seems definitively wrong to me. And it is also has nothing to do with `std::string` for MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/dra7sb3nh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think gcc is correct.  Specifically, clang is quite happy to compile this (and it runs correctly):

```
int main() {
    constexpr size_t N = make_ct_std_string().size();
    std::cout << ct_to_rt_string<N>(make_ct_std_string()).buffer;
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sTPUi1HHC9LGf33T)

So I guess it comes down to when the lifetime of the object used to evaluate the template argument is deemed to end, as @user17732522 points out.

It will also, FWIW, compile this:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << ct_to_rt_string<17>(make_ct_std_string()).buffer;
}
```

MSVC, however, still won't compile this code: https://godbolt.org/z/vdaKcaqY6

Comment: Thanks for your assessment and the workaround! I filed bug reports to [LLVM](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/62462) and [MSVC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Temporary-std::string-in-template-argume/10351855).

Comment: YW.  Feel free to accept :)